# Unable to register node js app in jhipster gateway

Tags: node.js, gateway, jhipster-registry, nodejs-server

I'm trying to register the node js application into Jhipster gateway by adding as zuul routes in the yml file. As you are aware, the node js application does not have the context path. Hence, it overrides the gateway url. Please help how to register node js app which does not have the context path.

```
 routes:
        NodeSample:
            path: /api/**
            url: http://localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the path as empty which leads to pick the url with serivce Id (NodeSample in my case) from jhipster gateway. Giving the empty path helps me have the correct url for node js application